# How to make it looking good sentence for line spacing

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

I develop some project, it works for tagging a words when i drag the words and click special button.

I want to make tags surrounding a word (begin & end tags with red color) (please refer exam picture, this)
but when it tagged at begin & end of text, it take null-spaces (like picture 2nd).
when I drag that spaces, there's no real space(white space or " " or "\nbsp" - no, never), that's just null space!

I can't select that space!

Pic. Link [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv4ba4gr8rlee2z/exam2.png)

here's my code below:

attribute:

```
static final Color TAG_COLOR = new Color(255, 50, 50);
static final Color PLAIN_TXT_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0);
public static SimpleAttributeSet plainAttr = new SimpleAttributeSet();
public static SimpleAttributeSet tagAttr = new SimpleAttributeSet();

StyleConstants.setAlignment(plainAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
StyleConstants.setForeground(plainAttr, PLAIN_TXT_COLOR);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(plainAttr, 11);
StyleConstants.setBold(plainAttr, false);

StyleConstants.setAlignment(tagAttr, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
StyleConstants.setForeground(tagAttr, TAG_COLOR);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(tagAttr, 11);
StyleConstants.setBold(tagAttr, true);
```

tagging function:

```
public static void tag_functiont() {
    String taggedName = "tagMark";
    int start_sel = mainEditText.getSelectionStart();
    int end_sel = mainEditText.getSelectionEnd();
    String selected = mainEditText.getSelectedText();
    StyledDocument doc = mainEditText.getStyledDocument();      
    if(selected == null || selected.isEmpty()) return;
    try {
        String bTag = "__B:"+taggedName+"__";
        String eTag = "__E:"+ taggedName +"__";

        doc.insertString(start_sel, bTag, tagAttr);
        doc.insertString(start_sel+bTag.length()+selected.length(), eTag, tagAttr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also worked all possibility of attributes options.
(some kinds of fonts, all kinds of arrangement;center, right, left, justified )

could someone gimme a piece of advice???

---

#### Solved

I added "  textPane.setContentType("html/text"); in main source, so foolish.
it triggered `<p> & <div>` tags.. so the paragraph are gone bad.

Comment: use HtmlDocument. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html

Comment: http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html you can use the link as an example

Comment: this, I also tried that one, but in my case, "html/text" makes whole this project harder, so I am trying to find other ways, except html.

Comment: mKorbel // thxs for editing title&tags